# rxjs pass parameter in Subject.next

Tags: typescript, rxjs, subject

I'm new to rxjs, I'm trying to pass parameter in `Subject.next(args)` I have the following class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ListPosts {
baseURL: string = 'http://localhost/wptest/api';
_load = new Subject();

constructor(private http: Http) {
    var currentPage = this._load
        .scan((currentPage) => currentPage + 1, 0)

    var postResponses = currentPage           //args here is undefined
        .flatMap(args => this.fetchPosts(args))
        .share();

    var loadedPosts = postResponses
        .map(json => json.posts)
        .scan((allPosts, newPosts) => allPosts.concat(newPosts), []);

    this.loadedPostCount = loadedPosts.map(p => p.length);
    this.totalPostCount = postResponses.map(json => json.count_total);

    this.completed = Observable.combineLatest(this.loadedPostCount, this.totalPostCount, (loaded, total) => loaded >= total);

    this.posts = loadedPosts;
}

fetchPosts(args: any) {
    console.log("count: " + args[0] + " page :" + args[1] + " type: "+ args[2]);
}

loadMore(args: any) {
    this._load.next(args);
}
}
```

but if I change `currentPage` to `this._load`, it works

```
var postResponses = this._load
        .flatMap(args => this.fetchPosts(args)) //args here is defined
        .share();
```

I need to get the args through `currentPage`, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to run the code? What do you expect currentPAge to get set to after scan()?

Comment: @bstockwell I get args is undefined. currentPage and the rest of the variables are used to calculate how many posts are loaded like `5/38 posts loaded` and disable "load more" button when it's done `38/38`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of points after looking at your code.

In `_load = new Subject();` the type parameter (or generic type if you will) is left out, so `_load` actually is of the default type `Subject<any>` (a.k.a. `Subject<{}>)`. It seems to me from looking at `fetchPosts` that you expect it to be of the type `any[]` or perhaps even `[number, string, string]`.

Would you have written `_load = new Subject<any[]>();` and `fetchPosts(args: any[])` typescript would have produced a type error, because the line: `.scan((currentPage) => currentPage + 1, 0)`  transforms the type parameter from type `any` to type `number`. This scan operation does nothing with the input, but simply increase a number `currentPage` starting at `0` for every type the Subject receives an input. If you then feed this number as `args` to `fetchPosts` and try to log `args[0]`, `args[1]` and `args[2]` you will get `undefined`, since a number is not an array. If you will log `args` itself you will find that you will see the currentPage number.

Here is something that might work for you or could give you an idea how your solution could work:

```
  type Args = [number, string, string];
  const _load = new Rx.Subject<Args>();
  const _loadCount = _load.scan(count => count + 1, 0);
  const _loadWithCount = Rx.Observable.zip(_load, _loadCount,
    (args, count) : Args => [count, args[1], args[2]]
  );
```

Comment: ".scan((currentPage) => currentPage + 1, 0) transforms the type parameter from type any to type number. " This is what I thought was happening too, but I'm not familiar enough with typescript to know for sure if that what was the case. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Typescript's type inference works pretty well. With scan the type of the second argument matches the type parameter of the Observable.

Comment: Thank you @LodewijkBogaards, this class is like a child component in angular2 `<posts [count]="5" [page]="1" [type]="'projects'"></posts>` count here means the count of posts I want to display in each click "loadmore", what you said about logging `args` alone is correct but not what I'm trying to accomplish, I just want to deliver `args` from function `loadMore` to function `fetchPost` as it is.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's rxjs 5 alpha 14

Comment: Then simply place `this._load` where you placed `currentPage` before the flatMap. I have already explained why you get the behavior you are getting. If you want `args` unchanged you can simply subscribe to `_load`, because `scan` changes the stream.

Comment: The only work around I reached so far is to make `args` as a property of the class and remove the arguments from `loadmore`.